# Oracle java jdbc bug

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I just simplified my code so anyone can reproduce the problem. Database data is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HBD."MY_OBJECT" AS OBJECT
(
VALUE VARCHAR2(1)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HBD."MY_COLLECTION" AS TABLE OF MY_OBJECT
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE HBD.MY_PACKAGE
IS
   --Obtener detalle de un contrato
   PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROCEDURE (
      out_value OUT NOCOPY HBD.MY_COLLECTION
   );
END MY_PACKAGE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY HBD.MY_PACKAGE
IS
   --Obtener detalle de un contrato
   PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROCEDURE (
      out_value OUT NOCOPY HBD.MY_COLLECTION
   )
   IS
   BEGIN
      out_value := MY_COLLECTION();
      FOR i IN 1..10920 LOOP
        out_value.EXTEND;
        out_value (i) := NEW MY_OBJECT ('A');
      END LOOP;
   END;
END MY_PACKAGE;
/
```

My java code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
        MalformedObjectNameException, NullPointerException,
        AttributeNotFoundException, InstanceNotFoundException,
        MBeanException, ReflectionException {

    System.out.println("Start");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ");

    String PROCEDURE = "{call MY_PACKAGE.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(?)}";

    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(PROCEDURE);
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "MY_COLLECTION");
    cs.execute();
    Array array = cs.getArray(1);
    if (array == null) {
        System.out.println("array == null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("array != null");
    }
    cs.close();
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

As you can see in the stored procedure there's a 10920. If I change this value to any other value. The output of the code will result in: array!=null. With the 10920 the output is: array==null.

Thanks in advance.
Joan

Comment: The bug is not in JDBC, looks to be in your Oracle driver.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if the MY_COLLECTION table has any number of entries other than 10920 everything works correctly?

Comment: Exact.
I'm using:
The driver is 11.2.0.3.0
The DBMS is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

And java 1.6.0.31

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the ojdbc*.jar file you are using is compatible with your version of
ORACLE:

classes12.jar - for Java 1.2 and 1.3
ojdbc14.jar - for Java 1.4 and 1.5
ojdbc5.jar - for Java 1.5
ojdbc6.jar - for Java 1.6

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3) JDBC Drivers

Download    ojdbc5.jar (2,095,932 bytes) - Classes for use with JDK 1.5. 
It contains the JDBC driver classes, except classes for NLS support in Oracle 
Object and Collection types.
Download    ojdbc5_g.jar (3,426,203 bytes) - Same as ojdbc5.jar, except 
that classes were compiled with "javac -g" and contain tracing code.

Download    ojdbc6.jar (2,714,189 bytes) - Classes for use with JDK 1.6. 
It contains the JDBC driver classes except classes for NLS support in Oracle 
Object and Collection types.
Download    ojdbc6_g.jar (4,463,274 bytes) - Sa

Instead of Types.ARRAY try using OracleTypes.ARRAY

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

cs.registerOutParameter(6, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "OHSI_CABECERA_CONTRATO");
cs.registerOutParameter(7, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "CHSI_HABITACION");
cs.registerOutParameter(8, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "CHSI_TARIFAS");
cs.registerOutParameter(9, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "CHSI_COMISION_WEB");
cs.registerOutParameter(10, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "CHSI_GRATUIDAD");
cs.registerOutParameter(11, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "CHSI_ESTANCIA_MINIMA");
```

After execute, use this code to check for and access the array

```
ARRAY array = (ARRAY) cs.getArray(1);
if (array != null && array.length() > 0) {
rs = array.getResultSet();
}
```

Comment: The value of Types.ARRAY and OracleTypes.ARRAY is the same.And it's not working.

Comment: You might want to check to make sure the ojdbc*jar file you're using is compatible with your ORACLE version.  I added the URL above..

Comment: Do you have this problem with OUT (when you remove the NOCOPY hint)?

Comment: Hello I've checked and I'm using java 1.6 with ojdbc6 which are compatibles.

Removing NOCOPY has the same result.

Comment: Any other recommendation?

Comment: Are you sure the procedure that you're calling, GET_DETAIL actually sets CHSI_ESTANCIA_MINIMA?  Does calling the procedure in PL/SQL, without JDBC work properly?

Comment: Try creating a procedure with only one OUT parameter: CHSI_ESTANCIA_MINIMA.  If that works consistently from JDBC, it is an ORACLE bug.